# php require and javascript

Tags: php, javascript, echo, require

I use this code to connect to a database:

```
@mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
@mysql_select_db("ECOLE") or die (mysql_error());
@mysql_set_charset('utf8');

if(isset($_POST['profname_in'])){
   $querycheck = "SELECT prof_som FROM prof_table 
                  WHERE prof_som=$_POST[profsom_in];";
   $_querycheck=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($querycheck));
   if(isset($_querycheck['prof_som'])){
     echo "0";
   }else{
     $query="INSERT INTO prof_table 
             VALUES('$_POST[profname_in]',
                    '$_POST[profcin_in]',
                    '$_POST[profsom_in]',
                    '$_POST[profville_in]',
                    '$_POST[profecole_in]',
                    '$_POST[profmat_in]',
                    '$_POST[profpass_in]');";
     if(mysql_query($query)){
           echo "1";
         }
   }
}
```

the echos is recupered by a javascript function (ajax):

```
function adding_prof_Reply() {

if(http.readyState == 4){ 
        var response = http.responseText;

     if(response==0){
            document.getElementById('prof_validation').innerHTML = '<font color="red">'+response+'</font>';
        }else if (response==1){
            document.location.href="dir_paneau.php";        
        }else{
            document.getElementById('prof_validation').innerHTML = '<font color="red">'+response+'</font>';
        }
}
}
```

everything works good, the problem is when I use `require('anyfile')` in the php code then the test `if(response==0)` is always false even when respose==0 ; if I remove the line of `require` everything works as it should.
I need the require to not repeat the connection information, any ideas?

Comment: Every SQL query in your code contains a profound SQL injection (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: The code in the question contains error suppression, there is no mention of *where* in the PHP the `require` function is being called, it isn't clear if "anyfile" really does mean "any file" or if it is a specific file that is not being shared with us, and there is no sign of any effort to debug the PHP independent of the JS by making HTTP requests to it directly from a browser (or cURL, etc).

Comment: @user1493590 - the PHP you posted does not include a call to `require()`. It sounds as though the required file is either error'ing or echo'ing a different output from that which your JS is expecting. Please *confirm* the output being received, don't assume it's 0. You can check this in Firebug/Dragonfly, or by visiting the script directly in the browser.

Comment: Can you post a HTML View source dump?

Comment: What are you using require() to call?! Without knowing that it's hard to say a thing, after all, you seem to suspect the issue is with that code after all!

Answer (score 0):

"i need the require to not repeat the connection information"

To only connect once, put the 'connection information' in a separate file, maybe `dbConnect.php` and use the function `require_once('dbConnect.php')` in the files which need a database connection.

This ensures you only connect to your database once, which may solve your problem.

Comment: no the problem is if i use require or require_once -and only in this case (whit ajax and java script)- it return the echos as i said but when i test the return in java script it return false even when it's should return a true!!.

Comment: do `alert(response)` just after you get the response, what does that give?

Comment: +1 @Tim, we cant even be sure what the response is thats coming through.

Comment: it gives even 1 or 0 (response catch the echo) the problem is when i do the test (response ==1) and respose=1 it return false!!and when a delete the require it return true

Comment: @user1493590 sorry but that doesn't make any sense, what code is the your file you are 'require'ing?

Comment: tankx Tim for trying to help;any file to make it more claire i'm using ajax to add data to database;it works fine but when i creat a new file `dbConnect.php` and i copy the first 3 lines to `dbConnect.php` then i use require('dbConnect.php') or even require_once('dbConnect.php') the problem starts

Comment: i found that if i encodeURIComponent(response) returns %EF%BB%BF%EF%BB%BF%20%20%200 when response=0 but when i encodeURIComponent(0) or encodeURIComponent('0') returns 0; ??

Comment: %EF%BB%BF is the [UTF BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), so it's sending back the UTF BOM twice, then 3 spaces (%20), and then your '0'. I've no idea why that is the case, maybe you're using some crazy text editor to create the files? Or maybe your text editor is set up to save the files as UTF-8 instead of ASCII text (it's best to save as ASCII files)? Quick solution would be to only compare the last character in the response variable.

Comment: Yes that's true i encode my pages with utf8 i use   <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
 in the page html and   <script type="text/javascript" src="../ajax/ajax_framework.js" charset="utf-8" language="javascript"></script> ;i also use arabic and french éèç ... what shoud i do?